# Is it possible to view a pdf image on android imageview

Tags: android, pdf, android-imageview

Hello I am looking at a type of drawing application that views images and would like to mark them up. Now I can load regular jpg and pngs, but our client has images in a pdf file. I am wondering if there is a way to display these on an image view in android.

Comment: PDFs are not images, so no. An image in a PDF file is like an image in a word document; you can't open up the document like a folder and select the image you want.

Comment: Check this answer out, its from a related question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019499/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-file-in-an-android-imageview